# How do I change what Rational Functional Tester logs?

Tags: functional-programming, rft, ibm-rational

Recently my company upgraded from RFT 8.1.1.1 to RFT 8.2 and now all of our rational_ft_log.txt files that get generated from tests are at least a dozen times longer than they were before we upgraded.

These files are so much longer now because every little "getProperty on frame" that happens returns a +++Pass, like this:

++ PASS 30-Mar-2011 11:15:43.113 AM   getProperty on the Frame
    line_number = 50
    script_name = DebugCommands.IR2_18_DebugCommands

Anyone know how to get rid of these nasty things?

I have searched exhaustively for RFT options to change, and I have looked a little into writing a plugin to output log files.  I can't seem to get IBM to get back to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own plugin, or just create your own custom logging methods in a super helper class. I do that anyway, to give me flexibility to output my logging info to any destination. But to answer your specific question about getting rid of the extraneous getProperty log messages, see the [RFT info center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/t_disablingenhancedlogresults.html):

> Logged events such as verification
>   point failures, script exceptions,
>   object recognition warnings, and other
>   additional playback information are
>   displayed in the playback log results.
>   From Rational® Functional Tester
>   version 8.2 and later, the results of
>   the getProperty() command are also
>   displayed in the log results. If you
>   do not require the log event to be
>   displayed in the playback log, you can
>   disable the event in the log results.
>
> Before you begin: Ensure that you have
>   access to modify the ivory.properties
>   file.
>
> About this task: To disable the
>   getProperty() log event, you must
>   modify the ivory.properties file.
>
> Procedure: Open the ivory.properties
>   file available in the \Functional
>   Tester\bin\ directory. Add the
>   following line of code at the end of
>   the file
>   contents:rational.test.ft.log.enhanced=false

Answer (score 1):

The fix is available under PMR29716. However, you would have to upgrade RFT8.2 to RFT 8.2.0.1 iFix01 to see it working.

Check the PMR @ https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24029194